# Clearing out UITableView

Tags: swift, tableview

I need a way to clear out a UITableView. Btw, I can't just clear out the data source and reload the UITableView. I have to remove all the cells from the UITableView.

Comment: What's the point of asking a question while refusing in advance to accept the answer?

Comment: maybe you should describe what you are trying to accomplish, big picture. Why can't you clear your data source when you want to clear the table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: z, section: 0) as IndexPath) as! Cusotmcell              
cell.contentView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Where `z` is index of cell

Answer (score 2):

> I can't just clear out the data source and reload the tableview

Well, that's too bad, because that's the answer. Clear out the data source, or at least throw a flag that causes `numberOfSections` to return `0` - and then reload the table view.

> I have to remove all the cells from the tableview

Yup, well, that's exactly what will happen if you do what I just said.